# How to dynamically get variables from query in PHP

Tags: php, url, parameters

So i am trying to implement a PHP program in which you can put in basically any kind of key and value given in the url query. So for example if i would put "www.domain.se/dispatch.php?randomkey=randomvalue" it would echo "randomkey=randomvalue" but if i then right in the browser add to it "www.domain.se/dispatch.php?randomkey=randomvalue&secondkey=secondvale" it would echo "randomkey=randomvalue
secondkey=secondvalue"

Right now i have only managed to get the first given key with this code and dont know how to move on. Any ideas? This is my code in dispatch.php:

```
      <?php
      $query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
      echo key($_GET);
      ?>
```

Comment: a simple `foreach( $_GET as $field => $value )` loop ??

Comment: be warned though - blindly accepting and printing values from a querystring opens the door to malicious code...

Comment: Yeah this is what i did eventually. New to PHP, it was of course very obvious & easy one. Thank you for the heads up, but its for a school thing so its fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `print_r` function to print an array in human readable format:

```
<?php print_r($_GET); ?>
```

or if you want to also see types use `var_dump` function:

```
<?php var_dump($_GET); ?>
```

If your practice is to use for loop this is answer:

```
for( $_GET as $key => $value )
    echo "$key : $value <br>";
```

Use above codes only for debug or during test period not in a production site to prevent security issues. Also consider using `htmlspecialchars` to prevent cross site scripting attacks.

Comment: Okay thank you nice. Im trying to get it to look like this: https://people.dsv.su.se/~pierre/i/05_ass/ip2/2/2.1/php/example.php?name=Nalle+Puh&email=nalle-puh@dsv.su.se. I assume now i just have to extract the keys from the array and work on it correct?

Answer (score 0):

So this piece of code nailed it:

```
    <?php
$query = ($_GET);
foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
    print_r($key. ": ". $value);
    echo '<br/>';
}
?>
```

But for anyone reading. Be aware as this is for school and as i have been warned this is not a secure way to deal with this.

Comment: Why using `print_r()` to print a string ?

Comment: I dont know.. It worked. Should i not use print_r?

Comment: there is no benefit in using `print_r` for strings. `echo` gives the same results. `print_r` is generally used to "dump" arrays or objects.